# Glide does not load all images (local files) (OutOfMemory)

Tags: android, android-glide

*Glide Version 4.9.0*

In my app I have 10 activities. The user clicks next on each activity in order to navigate to the next one until he eventually reaches the last activity.
The first 5 activities contain `ImageViews`.

The first 3 activities have one large `ImageView`.

Activity Four has 5 smaller `ImageViews`.

Activity Five has 8 smaller `ImageViews`.

_

The images to be loaded are located in the project resources in the `drawable` folder.

Before I used `Glide`, I simply used the `android:src` attribute of the `ImageView` in my xml-files,
which lead to the following error on a Galaxy S6 device when the user tries to open Activity Four with the 5 `ImageViews`:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 10240012 byte
>   allocation with 6982184 free bytes and 6MB until OOM

So I decided to use `Glide` to load the images into the `ImageViews` and removed the `android:src` attributes. The pictures looked blurry so I added `dontTransform()` to my statements:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.myImg1).dontTransform().skipMemoryCache(true).listener(new LoggingListener(getApplicationContext())).into(iv_p1);
```

On the emulator and my physical device (Xiaomi Mi A2 Android 9) everything looked fine.
The only downside of Glide is that you can see the `ImageViews` load their Images one after another.

On the Galaxy S6 that threw the `OutOfMemoryError` before, all the Activities showed without any errors.
But **only the first 4 of the 8** `ImageViews` loaded their images.
I was assuming that RAM was still an issue and that Glide just prevents an overflow by stopping loading images. So I resized my image files from 500x500 to 200x200.

Now the **first 6 of the 8** `ImageViews` loaded their images.

**LeakCanary** is not showing any leaks.

**Error Logs of Glide:**

```
Failed to load resource
There were 4 causes:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError(Failed to allocate a 26214412 byte allocation with 932280 free bytes and 910KB until OOM)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError(Failed to allocate a 26214412 byte allocation with 922168 free bytes and 900KB until OOM)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError(Failed to allocate a 2560012 byte allocation with 914680 free bytes and 893KB until OOM)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError(Failed to allocate a 2560012 byte allocation with 937496 free bytes and 915KB until OOM)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

I can't really go lower with the resolution without dropping quality and even if I would set the resolution low enough to show all images on the device it's not guaranteed that other devices with even lower memory show all the images, too.

I can't reproduce this behaviour on my own device or any of the emulators (not even when setting RAM of emulator to minimum of 128MB).
Is it possible to unload the images of the current activity when going to the next one in order to free some memory?

**EDIT:**

Memory on emulator goes from 40 MB at start up to 220 MB after loading all the images. The images are JPG files with 200x200 pixels.

Preview of the following xml layout:

[image]

Here is the xml layout of the activity with 8 ImageViews:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_main5"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="end"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingEnd="10dp"
 />

<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/step5"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dreieck_wild"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

          />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/dreieck_wild" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/langloch"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/langloch"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/quadrat"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_p3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb33"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/quadrat"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/raute_versetzt"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_p4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb44"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/raute_versetzt"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/raute"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_p5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb55"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/raute"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rundloch_klein"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_p6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb66"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/rundloch_klein"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"

    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rundloch_wild"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_p7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb77"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/rundloch_wild"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/schachbrett"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_p8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb88"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/schachbrett"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/next"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all images when leaving the activity and then re-adding all images when coming back to the Activity keeps the memory low enough to work on most devices.

**In each Activity:**

```
@override
protected void onStart() {
    Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.img).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache(true).dontTransform().into(imageView);
    super.onStart();
}

@override
protected void onStop() {
    Glide.with(this).clear(imageView);
    super.onStop();
}
```

**Also**

Providing images for different screen resolutions can help keeping the memory usage as low as possible. I used [NativeScript Image Builder](http://nsimage.brosteins.com/) to create all my assets.

Answer (score 0):

```
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
```

Comment: I will have it tested. But doesn't this refer to Disk cache rather than RAM?

Comment: Just had it tested. No difference at all

Answer (score -1):

Try to change Glide code like:

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(R.drawable.myImg1)
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .dontTransform().into(iv_p1);
```

Also if your image not changing dynamically(Means if there are any images which is loading dynamically and will not be changed dynamically) then add line:

`.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)`

Comment: My bad. Forgot to mention I tried this already. Updated the line of code in my post.

Comment: OK! I understand. But also don't use `setHasStableIds(true);` its causing also more memory!

Comment: I don't use it, unless it's a default.  And DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC is default